# Стоит ли создавать отдельную метку `telegrambots` в ruSO, если есть похожая, но другая?

Tags: обсуждение, создание-метки

#### Update #1:

На мой взгляд, данная метка должна присутствовать на ruSO, потому что у людей могут возникать вопросы, которые напрямую связаны с данной библиотекой, а не с телеграм-ботами в целом.

Вот пример вопросов:

- Как создавать телеграм бота вместе с Spring Boot
- Как отправлять сообщения в телеграм из других классов
- Какая разница между AbilityBot и TelegramLongPollingBot
- Как отправлять видео в телеграм
- Как отправлять фотографии, если мне известна лишь ссылка и сохранять фотографию локально не требуется.

Помогите, пожалуйста, добавить ее в перечень меток. Если метка должна быть
вставлена в вопрос, чтобы добавить в перечень, то [добавьте ее сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1142473/275232)

---

SO, когда я задавал вопрос, порекомендовал мне написать в мете вопрос о том, что я использую метку `telegrambots`, которая похожа с меткой `telegram-bot`.

Стоит отметить, что метка `telegram-bot` - это метка связанная с Telegram Bot API, в то время как `telegrambots` больше относится к Java-библиотеке [TelegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots).

Вопрос-предложение: Стоит ли создавать отдельную метку `telegrambots` в ruSO для  отделения вопросов, связанные с Java-библиотекой, которую я указал выше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоит отметить, что метка [tag:telegram-api] не связана с разработкой ботов телеграм

Comment: @mymedia я это лично понимаю... Т.к. не существуют отдельные метки по telegram-библиотекам для создания ботов, люди лепят тэг [tag:telegram-api] .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Звучит логично, метку на вопрос повесил, описание какое-то добавил (хорошо бы его улучшить). Надо повесить метку ещё хотя бы на один вопрос, чтобы её потом Дух не удалил.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Я тогда сейчас займусь добавлением вопросов, которые я написал в данном своём посте.

Comment: метка безликая, одноимённых библиотек однозначно больше 1. кмк, это порождает неопределённость. стоит наверное добавить язык, раз уж это метка по конкретной реализации